# How to drop all table in MySQL?

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

I don't want to drop database,

because I'm not hosting the website on my own machine,

drop the database will require create it again,and many settings.

Is there a command in MySQL that can be used to delete all tables in a specific database?

**EDIT**

Everything I can do is within a **phpMyAdmin**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> mysqldump -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD]
>   --add-drop-table --no-data [DATABASE] | grep ^DROP | mysql -u[USERNAME]
>   -p[PASSWORD] [DATABASE]

[Here](http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/blog/10-10-2006/mysql-drop-all-tables) there are more methods to drop all tables without dropping the database.

Comment: How do I use your script with when I get this error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: @user2298943 Use this:  
`mysqldump -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] --add-drop-table --no-data [DATABASE] | grep -e '^DROP \| FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS' | mysql -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] [DATABASE]`

Answer (score 46):

You were talking about doing this in phpMyAdmin.

I just had to do this and I'm not sure what version you are using but in the version I have if you scroll to the bottom of the table list you can click "Check All" and then in the drop down next to it that has "With Selected:" you can select "Drop" and it empties all the tables.

Comment: This is the actual answer for this question.

Comment: It works! But i disabled verify foreign key to drop all tables!

Answer (score 8):

You can also generate a sql file from the information_schema database:

```
Select concat('DROP TABLE database_name.', table_name,';') from information_schema.TABLES where table_schema='database_name';
```

This will give an output like:

```
DROP TABLE database_name.table1;
DROP TABLE database_name.table2;
[...]
DROP TABLE database_name.tableN;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of anything direct to suit your needs. You might try doing the following:

Run this to show your drop commands:

```
mysqldump -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] --add-drop-table --no-data [DATABASE] | 
grep ^DROP
```

Nex you can do this to actually execute the drop commands:

```
mysqldump -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] --add-drop-table --no-data [DATABASE] | 
grep ^DROP | 
mysql -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] [DATABASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$q=mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM ".SQL_DATABASE_NAME);

while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
    mysql_query("DROP TABLE ".$r["Tables_in_".SQL_DATABASE_NAME]); 
}
```

it work for me!

Answer (score 0):

If your table names have only simple names (no spaces or other special chars) this query could build the whole drop command for you:

```sql
select concat('drop table ', group_concat(table_name), ';') from information_schema.tables where table_schema='yourdbname';
```